# Unpack a specific key from json column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My data look like:

```
col1   
[{"key":"1", "count":5, "desc":"blah"},{"key":"2", "count":3, "desc":"meh"}]
[{"key":"2", "count":23, "desc":"qwe"},{"key":"44", "count":0, "desc":""}]
```

I want to create new column which will include only the "key"'s values:

```
new_col   
["1", "2"]
["2", "44"]
```

I tried to parse the json in some ways but didn't find a reasonable way to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of JSON object in one cell. You can use `FLATTEN` on your variant column to be able to select from it as it was in multiple rows. Then you extract the key from it and aggregate as an array. Try this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(FLATTENED.value:key) AS new_col
FROM my_variant_table, -- replace with your table name
     LATERAL FLATTEN(input => col1) AS FLATTENED
GROUP BY col1;
```

--group by I used to ensure the uniqueness of the rows